# How can I change the default text on the "Submit" button?

Tags: google-forms

Can somebody please tell me how to change text on the *Submit* button in Google Forms?

Please note:

- I am referring here to the standard Google Forms, the one's that
  anyone can setup in Google Drive by clicking on the *New* button and
  then selecting Google Forms in the drop down menu.
- I am not referring to the more complex Google forms which require
  Google Scripting knowledge to setup. I mention this because I have
  searched the online lots for the answer to my question and several
  times the setText('text button') function has been mentioned. From
  what I can see this only applies to the these more complex customised
  forms. If that's not correct and I can use this function to get the
  job done, then please explain how.
- This question is also frequently confused with how do I change the
  "Thank you for submitting details" text after the form is submitted.
  This is not what I am looking for.
- Here is a link to a standard Test Google Form, just asking for Name
  and Email address. I have changed the access type to anyone with
  link. So if it's easier to do the edit, instead of trying to explain
  how to do it, please do so on [this form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/17Nx1VGvYNchz3KBE9vRORneUwQsMvdqV0r8-szE2UIA/edit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: *You can't do that using Google's form builder*.

The longer answer is that you *can* copy the form's HTML code and host it on your own website. That HTML code may then be modified to have the button display any text you'd like.
Copying and hosting the HTML code does have its drawbacks. If you edit the form from Google's form builder, the copied HTML code will of course not be updated, so you'd have to copy and mofiy it again.

See [this article from ohdoylerules.com](http://ohdoylerules.com/web/custom-google-forms) for how to copy and host the HTML code. Note that in this article, they are using Google Drive to host their customised HTML. That feature is [not available in *new* Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en), so you will have to host your HTML somewhere else.

I have created a demo form here: http://vvv.vidarramdal.com/stackoverflow/webapps-66392/

```
I have searched the online lots for the answer to my question and several 
times the setText('text button') function has been mentioned. From what I can 
see this only applies to the these more complex customised forms. If that's 
not correct ...
```

No, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

When you copy the HTML code from the form to a page on a website, you can change not only the (text of the) submit button, but also the layout of the questions and more!

Comment: I'm looking for a way to this without copying the HTML, each form is reused across the site many times. If I use the form HTML and I then need to change something on the form, each form would need to be updated individually.

Is there no way to do this with a Google script?